# Questions in the Proof of Riesz Representation Theorem for $C_0(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm going through the proof of Riesz Representation Theorem for $C_0(X)$, namely Theorem $6.19$ in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*. I have the following questions from the theorem's proof, which assume the existence of a positive linear functional $\Lambda$ on $C_c(X)$ such that $|\Phi(f)| \le \Lambda(|f|) \le \|f\|$ for $f\in C_c(X)$ (see Equation 4). This is proved later, in what follows Equation 8. For reference, I've attached the proof at the end of this post. I've highlighted in blue

---

1. Why can $\{f_n\}$ be chosen so that $$\int_X |\bar h - f_n|\, d |\mu| \xrightarrow{n\to\infty 
   } 0$$
2. Why is $|\Lambda f|\le 1$ when $\|f\| \le 1$? The inequality right before says $|\Lambda |f|| \le \|f\|$, for $f\in C_c(X)$.
3. Why is each side of $(6)$ a continuous functional on $C_0(X)$? $(6)$ holds for $C_c(X)$, which is a subset of $C_0(X)$.
4. How does $(6)$ imply $(7)$, i.e. $$\int_X |g|\,d\lambda \ge \sup\{|\Phi(f)| : f\in C_0(X), \|f\|\le 1\} = 1$$
5. Why are $\lambda(X) \le 1$ and $|g|\le 1$ compatible only when $\lambda(X) = 1$ and $|g| = 1$ a.e. $[\lambda]$?

---

[image]
[image]

After this, they construct a positive linear functional $\Lambda$ that satisfies $(4)$, hence completing the proof.

If you need any clarifications, please let me know (including statements of any other theorems which have been mentioned in the above discourse, in case you do not have the book handy and want to have a look.) Thanks for any input!

Comment: As for (1), Rudin himself mentions that it is because $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^1(|\mu|)$. (2) is because $|f|-f\ge 0$, and since $\Lambda$ is positive then $\Lambda f\le \Lambda\,|f|$. (3) is because $|\int_X fg\,d\lambda|\le \lambda(X)\lVert f\rVert\le \lVert f\rVert$, so both sides are equal by density. For (4) is $|\Phi(f)| = |\int fg\,d\lambda|$ by (6), then $|\Phi(f)| \le \int_X|g|\,d\lambda$. For the last, if those conditions didn't meet, from (7) we'd get $1>1$.

Comment: (1) is still not clear to me. Are you suggesting that $h\in L^1(|\mu|)$, and if yes, why?

Comment: Because $|h| = 1$, so $\rVert h\rVert_1 = |\mu|(X)<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I still do not understand (4) and (5) well. For (4): Why is $$\sup\{|\Phi(f)| : f\in C_0(X), \|f\|\le 1\} = 1$$ true? The other inequality is clear. For (5): I'm trying to find a contradiction by assuming $\lambda(X) < 1$ **or** $|g| < 1$ on a set of positive measure w.r.t. $\lambda$. Could you please add more details (maybe as an answer)?

Comment: (4): the identity comes from the assumption $\lVert\Phi\rVert = 1$. (5) suppose, e.g., that $|g|\le 1-\epsilon$ in a set $A\subset X$ with $\lambda(A)>0$, then $\int|g|d\lambda \le \lambda(A^c)+(1-\epsilon)\lambda(A)<\lambda(X)\le 1$.